# Is there any way to recover backups already automatically removed from iCloud?

Tags: icloud

I need a backup from a week ago, but only have last two days.

The backups were automatically removed from iCloud, so I cannot recover from deleted items.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about backups of iOS devices, then no, there's no functionality for recovering an already removed/deleted iCloud backup of an iOS device.

If you're talking about "manual backups" you might have made - i.e. manually copying over files to the iCloud Drive or similar, you should be able to recover them from icloud.com. However, I doubt that this is your situation.